# python while with if/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

It's for my school work. I need to fix this code. Can someone maybe help me? I would really appreciate that. I can't manage to fix the "else" part. :)

```
CorrectUsername = "Username"
CorrectPassword = "Password"

loop = 'true'
while (loop == 'true'):
username = raw_input("Please enter your username: ")
if (username == CorrectUsername):
password = raw_input("Please enter your password: ")
if (password == CorrectPassword):
print "Logged in successfully as " + username
loop = 'false'
else:
print "Password incorrect!"
else:
print "Username incorrect!"
```

This is what I've done so far

```
CorrectUsername = "Username"
CorrectPassword = "Password"

loop = "true"
while (loop == 'true'):
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    if (username == CorrectUsername):
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        if (password == CorrectPassword):
            print("Logged successfully as " + str(username))
            loop = "false"
    else:
        print("Password incorrect!")
        else:
            print("Username incorrect")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! What are you trying to do with the else block?

Comment: Why are using strings instead of booleans?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) In your case, you should explain what is wrong with your code and what you are trying to achieve here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indent the `else` properly it's matching `if`. Also use boolean values `True/False`, better than strings

```
CorrectUsername = "Username"
CorrectPassword = "Password"

loop = True
while loop:
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    if username == CorrectUsername:
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        if password == CorrectPassword:
            print("Logged successfully as " + str(username))
            loop = False
        else:
            print("Password incorrect!")
    else:
        print("Username incorrect")
```

Comment: @RobertsKrūmiņš you can think about accepting the answer so (green tick onleft) ;)